# Parsing HTTP Get requests into constituent fields

Tags: java, http, parsing, http-headers, http-get

I have fields like:

```
"GET /?blahblahblah HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/" 1 blahblah - "en-gb" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB0.0; FunWebProducts; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

i'm looking for a java library or code that can decode this, parse it apart, and provide programatic access to the components, especially the user agent info. googling didnt turn up anything useful, but as this info is used all the time, there must be existing systems for doing what i require.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use [Apache HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/index.html). The interface you're looking for it [HttpRequest](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html) and a simple implementation is [BasicHttpRequest](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/index.html).

Constructing the HttpRequest is dependent on how you get the request itself to begin with, but for example, in a little web server I'm working on, it's simply:

```
DefaultHttpServerConnection serverConnection = new DefaultHttpServerConnection();
serverConnection.bind(socket, params);
HttpRequest httpRequest = serverConnection.receiveRequestHeader();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an apache **LOG** parser.  You may find [JXLA](http://jxla.nvdcms.org/en/) useful, or google for "Java apache log parser".